# vue router Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

i'm using vue router and its work and navigate to other pages but gives me errors:

```
Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

i didn't used router.push or something like this.

this is my loop and router link:

```
 <swiper-slide v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <router-link :to="`/tour/` + item.slug">
                                    <img :src="item.img" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded rounded-circle" :alt="item.title">
                                    <h3 class="pt-3">{{ item.title }}</h3>
                                </router-link>
                            </div>
                        </swiper-slide>
```

and this is my route:

```
        {
            path: '/tour/:tour',
            component: Tour,
            name: 'tour'
        },
```

Comment: try adding `router-link` like this `to="/tour/" + item.slug` or  `to="tour/" + item.slug`

Comment: @AbdulBasit its wrong

Comment: can you please post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'tour', params: { tour: 'mySlug' }}">...</router-link>
```

Comment: still getting error and one warning: ```missing param for named route "tour": Expected "tour" to match "[^\/]+?", but received ""```

Comment: ```<router-link :to="{ name: 'tour', params: { tour: item.slug }}">
                                    <img :src="item.img" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded rounded-circle" :alt="item.title">
                                    <h3 class="pt-3">{{ item.title }}</h3>
                                </router-link>```